# Pandas: find substring in a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to find in dataframe some strings

```
url
003.ru/*/mobilnyj_telefon_bq_phoenix*
003.ru/*/mobilnyj_telefon_fly_*
003.ru/*mobile*
003.ru/telefony_i_smartfony/mobilnye_telefony_smartfony
003.ru/telefony_i_smartfony/mobilnye_telefony_smartfony/%brands%5D%5Bbr_23%
1click.ru/*iphone*
1click.ru/catalogue/chasy-motorola
```

problen in next: when I use

```
df_update = df[df['url'].str.contains(substr.url)]
```

it return error, because some `url` contain `*`.
How can I fix that problem?

Comment: `df[df['url'].str.contains(substr.url, regex=False)]`?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df[df['url'].str.contains(substr.url, regex=False)]
```

You have to specify whether or not you want your pattern to be interpreted as a regular expression or a normal string. In this case, you want to set the `regex` argument to `False` because it is set to `True` by default. That way, the asterisks in your pattern won't be interpreted as regular expression.

I hope this helps.

Comment: if `*` means any character?

Comment: The asterisk is a metacharacter which indicates zero or more occurrences of the previous element. Basically whenever it's in a pattern it means that the element before it is expected zero or more times. Google ***regular expression*** for more information.